# about a summary problem from middle school

Tags: summation, special-functions

if we have a function $I_a=1+2^{a}x^{1}+3^{a}x^2+……+p^{a}x^{p-1}$
how can i write the general term of $I_a$?
i think it must be fantastc.i havent use this before,please forgive me about grammar mistakes and writing.thank you for answering!

Comment: It can be written in terms of the polylogarithm and Lerch transcendent.

Comment: Are you asking for closed form? Or for notation shortcut? If latter, you can write $I_a=\sum_{k=1}^{p}k^a x^{k-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

As @ K.defaoite commented,
$$I_a=\sum_{k=1}^{p}k^a \,x^{k-1}=\frac{\text{Li}_{-a}(x)}{x}-x^p\, \Phi (x,-a,p+1)$$
$$I_\infty=\frac{\text{Li}_{-a}(x)}{x}$$

Comment: Polylogarithms on middle school? Really?

Comment: I AM just a middle school student and I can only do the recurrence form.thank you for answering!